# My MySQL server is constantly crashing, why is that?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two sites, with fairly zero daily traffic. Both runs woocommerce with 100-100 products (each has 200-300 variations). It runs on a VPS (1GB, 1CPU), and the site constantly crashes, and I need to restart the MySQL service. The hosting company said the RAM is full, but I don't really get it why it should crash my whole site, with 10 visitors a day... I hope you guys can help :)

Here is the log.

```
   150406 11:05:41 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150406 11:15:43 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150406 11:15:43 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150406 11:15:43 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150406 11:15:43 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150406 11:15:43 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150406 11:15:43 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150406 11:15:43 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150406 11:15:43 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150406 11:15:43 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
150406 11:15:43  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
150406 11:15:44  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150406 11:15:45 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 806004238
150406 11:15:45 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
150406 11:15:45 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
150406 11:15:45 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
150406 11:15:45 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150406 11:15:45 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
150406 11:15:46 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './pamutlabor/wp_betaoptions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
150406 11:15:46 [Warning] Checking table:   './pamutlabor/wp_betaoptions'
150406 13:20:45 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150406 13:20:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150406 13:20:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150406 13:20:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150406 13:20:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150406 13:20:45 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150406 13:20:46 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
150406 13:20:46 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150406 13:20:46 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
150406 13:20:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150406 13:20:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150406 13:20:46 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150406 13:20:46 [ERROR] Aborting

150406 13:20:46 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150406 13:20:47 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150406 13:20:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150406 13:20:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150406 13:20:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150406 13:20:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150406 13:20:47 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150406 13:20:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
150406 13:20:47 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150406 13:20:47 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
150406 13:20:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150406 13:20:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150406 13:20:47 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150406 13:20:47 [ERROR] Aborting

150406 13:20:47 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150406 13:33:45 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150406 13:33:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150406 13:33:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150406 13:33:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150406 13:33:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150406 13:33:45 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150406 13:33:45 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150406 13:33:45 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150406 13:33:45 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
150406 13:33:45  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
150406 13:33:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150406 13:33:47 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 806115911
150406 13:33:47 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
150406 13:33:47 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
150406 13:33:47 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
150406 13:33:47 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150406 13:33:47 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
150406 13:33:49 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './pamutlabor/wp_betaoptions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
150406 13:33:49 [Warning] Checking table:   './pamutlabor/wp_betaoptions'
150406 13:33:51 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './pamutlabor/wp_betarg_form_view' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
150406 13:33:51 [Warning] Checking table:   './pamutlabor/wp_betarg_form_view'
150406 13:33:51 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './teetaku/wp_galleryvotes' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
150406 13:33:51 [Warning] Checking table:   './teetaku/wp_galleryvotes'
```

Comment: I don't know your whole configuration but 1GB may be not enough for GNU/Linux + MySQL + some HTTP server + wordpres + ... See what dmesg tells you (if you are able to reach server's shell).

Comment: I am planning to upgrade to 2GB, but I suppose moving to a managed hosting provider would be my best option on the long run. 2GB might be enough for the site "not to crash", but when it starts to generate a few hundred, or thousand visitors/day even 4-8gb won't be enough and I will pay a lot :/